# How do I sum parts of rows into several columns based on parameters from a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to summarize parts of a delivery in terms of weight (and also value) but I fail to make it work when I group by deliveryNo which is what I want/need. I also need to group by type to get correct summarizations in each columns which causes extra rows and I need 1 row per deliveryNo and I have tried several solutions with case and subequeries but I'm not managing to get this correct.

Example below. To clarify, the type is a value connected to each row from another table, and weight is also from a separate table but the tables are linked with an articleNo.

| deliveryNo | type | amount | weight | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 25 |
| 123 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 26 |
| 123 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 24 |
| 123 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 20 |
| 123 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 10 |

What I want to achieve is this: (settling for weight but the value will be used, but I reckon the principal will be the same)

| deliveryNo | weighttype1 | weighttype2 | weighttype3 | weightRest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 | 10 | 4 | 34 |

Comment: Can you please explain the logic also? Why weighttype3 is 4 and weightRest is 34.

Comment: Sorry, the summarized weight is the amount x weight and I want each type of 1,2 and 3 summarized separately in 1 column each and all other types summarized together in a fourth column.